# Why do I see a "View answer" link for all of my answers?

Tags: discussion

Why do I see the link text as *View answer* for all of my answers?

[image: View answer]

Comment: Already reported and [tag:status-review]: [No titles or contents in answer list on profile page, only “View Answer”](/q/377188/289905).